# fullcalendar with rails - limit results to a range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I've got fullcalendar working with a small rails app (yeah) but it's sluggish because the find in my controller is finding ALL the records before it renders the calendar. I'm using a JSON approach. The field names I'm using are `starts_at` and `ends_at`. This (in the `index` method of the `assignments_controller`) works:

```
@assignments = Assignment.find(:all, :conditions => "starts_at IS NOT NULL")
```

But, as I said, it's pokey, and will only get worse as more records get added.
So this is clearly more of a rails question than a fullcalendar question: I can't figure out how to get fullcalendar to initially display the current week (when no parameters have been sent) and then accept parameters from next/previous buttons while, in either case, *only* looking up the relevant items from the database.

Oh - this is rails 2.x, NOT 3.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: please post a bit more code so we know how you pass records to the calendar

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question.
It turned out to be an issue with Date format inconsistencies between JavaScript (Epoch) and Ruby. At least that's what I think at the moment.
I'm still scratching my head, trying to figure out how exactly I "fixed" it, but it seems to be working.
I was aware of this project: http://github.com/bansalakhil/fullcalendar
but it took me ages to get the nuance of Time.at figured out.

I must say, Time is a tricky thing.
In real life as well as in code.

Thanks to everyone who gave my (misguided, as it turned out) question a glance.